# Get activity status of users / bots - Discord Bot .NET application

Tags: discord, discord.net

I'm making a discord bot which, for an initial phase, will need to be able to view the status / activity of a user (my only intention is for it to be able to view status of another imported bot).

I have enabled Server Intent, amongst the other server settings.
[image]

I have been trying to make a custom oAuth URL with 'bot' and 'activity.read', but am struggling to get it to import to Discord server properly. Depending on the settings and URL I use, it appears to import right, but when debugging the application, it still shows Status as Offline, and Activity count as 0, even though I can see that the custom activity is not empty on discord for the user / bot I'm using.

There doesn't seem to be much knowledge on Activities for Discord bots, at least not for .NET, so I'm looking for any help on this.

Just to clarify, the problem is that the Activity for a user is always empty, even though I can clearly see that the activity is displaying text.

Debugging User (bot)
[image]

Discord status (bot)

[image]

Thank you for any answers

Comment: You probably need to include the presence intent in your socket client config

Comment: @Anu6is I currently have this as the DiscordSocketClient, not seeing an option to add PresenceIntent. Would you mind elaborating on that? Thank you

These are the following GatewayIntents in place
GatewayIntents.AllUnprivileged 
GatewayIntents.GuildPresences 
GatewayIntents.GuildMembers

Comment: GuildPresences is what I was referring to. Not sure what else your issue might be